# Counterexample to Kolmogorov extension theorem

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I know that given a space $(E, \epsilon)$ (with some properties, but whatever) and a consistent family of finite dimensional distributions, I have Kolmogorov extension theorem that tells there is a probability $\mu$ on $(E^T, \epsilon ^T)$ with those distributions.

I have been told that if I stopped at distributions of order $m$ I could always find a counterexample where I have a consistent family of distributions up to order  $m$ that doesn’t come from any distribution $\mu$ on $(E^T, \epsilon ^T)$.

I don’t see how to construct such counterexample, though.

Comment: The set of functions from $T$ (set of times) to $E$ and its corresponding sigma algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m=3$, with $T=\{1,2,3\}$ and suppose  $(X_1,X_2)$ was uniform on $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ and so was $(X_1,X_3)$ and so was $(X_2,X_3)$.  And that the $X_i$ are individually uniform on $\{0,1\}$. This specifies  all $1$ and $2$-dimensional margins for $\{X_t:t\in S\}$ for all $S\subset T$ with $| S|<3$. There is no joint probability for $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, because it would put all the mass on elements of $\{0,1\}^3$ whose components were all distinct.  There are no such elements, as any combo of 3 zeros and ones must contain a duplicate.

Put another way, $P(X_1=1-X_2)=P(X_3=1-X_2)=1$ from which one might guess $P(X_1=X_3)=1$, but the posited margin for $(X_1,X_3)$ says no.

Comment: Wait, what set are you taking? Sorry but I don’t get if those are coordinates, intervals or what. Also, why isn’t there joint distribution? It would give an absurd somehow, right?

Comment: Hopefully clearer after rewrite.

Comment: Ok let’s see if I got this. You put all the mass on the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ for all the 2-distributions. It isn’t possible to have a joint distribution because the probability should be put in points where $X_1 \neq X_2 \neq X_3$, and that’s impossible

Comment: Yes.  I've added a bit more along those lines.

Comment: I was thinking: is this choice consistent with 1 dimensional distributions? I should obtain a consistent family of 1 and 2 distribution